# Nuxt build/generate dont aplying buefy css table

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, buefy

I have a problem when building my nuxt application to production.
When executed in dev mode the style looks great but when made the nuxt generate the styles gone from this table.

The component is b-table.

Here my nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,
  
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    VUE_API_URL: process.env.VUE_API_URL
  },

  // Disable startup telemetry check
  telemetry: false,

  // Listen on all interfaces
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000,
  },

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'LS Tractor',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'pt-br',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: 'favicon.ico' }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  // css: ["@/assets/styles.scss"],
  css: [
    {
      src: '@/assets/powerbox.scss',
      lang: 'sass'
    }
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vuex-persist.ts',
    '~/plugins/services.ts',
    '~/plugins/goTo.ts'
  ],
  
  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/stylelint
    '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/composition-api',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
  ],

  buefy: {
    materialDesignIcons: true,
    defaultIconPack: 'fas',
    defaultIconComponent: 'font-awesome-icon'
  },

  fontawesome: {
    imports: [
      {
        set: '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
        icons: ['fas']
      }
    ]
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/buefy
    'nuxt-buefy',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    'nuxt-buefy',
    'nuxt-fontawesome'
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_API_URL,
    credentials: true,
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuex-module-decorators', 'vuex-persist'],
  },

  generate: {
    dir: 'ged'
  },

  router: {
    base: '/ged/'
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      laravelSanctum: {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: process.env.VUE_API_URL,
        user: {
          property: 'user',
          autoFetch: false
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/login_api',
            method: 'post'
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Here how looks like in dev mode:

[image]

Below is the application rendering in production mode:

[image: Here when generated]

Below is the code from my component:

```
<b-table id="teste-evaluators" :data="evaluators">
          <b-table-column class="td-name" field="name" label="Nome" v-slot="props">
            {{ props.row.evaluator_name }}
          </b-table-column>
          <b-table-column class="td-name" field="name" label="Avaliado em" v-slot="props">
            {{ props.row.created_at ? props.row.created_at : 'Não avaliado' }}
          </b-table-column>
          <b-table-column centered label="Status" v-slot="props">
            <b-tooltip v-if="props.row.approved === 'Y'" class="tooltip approve-icon" label="Aprovado" type="is-success" position="is-left">
              <svg style="width:20px;height:20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="M12 2C6.5 2 2 6.5 2 12S6.5 22 12 22 22 17.5 22 12 17.5 2 12 2M10 17L5 12L6.41 10.59L10 14.17L17.59 6.58L19 8L10 17Z" />
              </svg>
            </b-tooltip>
            <b-tooltip v-else-if="props.row.approved === null" class="tooltip warning-icon" label="Aguardando avaliação" type="is-warning" position="is-left">
              <svg style="width:20px;height:20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="M13,13H11V7H13M13,17H11V15H13M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" />
              </svg>
            </b-tooltip>
            <b-tooltip v-else class="tooltip disapprove-icon" label="Reprovado" type="is-danger" position="is-left">
              <svg style="width:20px;height:20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="M12,2C17.53,2 22,6.47 22,12C22,17.53 17.53,22 12,22C6.47,22 2,17.53 2,12C2,6.47 6.47,2 12,2M15.59,7L12,10.59L8.41,7L7,8.41L10.59,12L7,15.59L8.41,17L12,13.41L15.59,17L17,15.59L13.41,12L17,8.41L15.59,7Z" />
              </svg>
            </b-tooltip>
          </b-table-column>
        </b-table>
```

Comment: Does it work locally with `yarn generate && yarn start`?

Comment: nope, doesnt work, only with yarn dev

Comment: What is the issue there? Is there an error or something wrong?

Comment: @kissu nothing wrong on console :/

Comment: Try inspecting it with your browser inspector and see if something overrides it or alike.